# Composability of @func.apply() SpEL authorization methods

Tags: spring-security

Does the new Spring Security 6 approach for authorization using @Bean functions in SpEL expressions support composing multiple @Bean functions in the same SpEL expression? For example, given the following configuration (Kotlin):

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity(useAuthorizationManager = true)
@Configuration
class MethodSecurityConfig {
    @Bean func1() : Function<UUID, Mono<Boolean>> {...}

    @Bean func2() : Function<UUID, Mono<Boolean>> {...}
}
```

can something like the following be done?

```
...
    @PreAuthorize("@func1.apply(#id) and @func2.apply(#id)")
    fun action(id: UUID) {
    ...
    }
```

If so, how?

It seems composability is supported for the built in `SecurityExpressionRoot` methods, but not for custom `@Bean` methods. If not, is the only alternative a new `@Bean` authorization method for each combination that's needed, given that `@PreAuthorize` is not a repeatable annotation?